# Animating NMAMapCircle object along a map

Tags: here-api

Say I have 2 `NMAGeoCoordinates` to place my `NMAMapCircle` on my `NMAMapView`. They are `(33,180)` and `(34,180)`. Is it possible to animate the `NMAMapCircle` moving from coordinates `(33,180)` to `(34,180)`?

Answer (score 0):

Just interpolate the latitude yourself over a fixed time? Keep changing the position of the maker will make it look like an animation. Normally we do this @30fps, but even at 15fps it looks pretty good.